# Can't Get jQuery Easy Slider Plugin to Work - Please Help

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, easyslider

I'm using the Easy Slider extension for jQuery on my website and can't get it working properly. I have used it before an not had any issues. It is being called successfully and some features of Easy Slider are working but not everything.

Sample Page: http://174.120.138.5/~mjbradle/
CSS: http://174.120.138.5/~mjbradle/sites/all/themes/mjb/main.css
JS: http://174.120.138.5/~mjbradle/sites/all/themes/mjb/slider.js
JS: http://174.120.138.5/~mjbradle/sites/all/themes/mjb/main.js

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Chuck

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What do you mean not working? I had a look at it, and it doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In main.js, you're instantiating the slider on the `jQuery(".home-slide > ul")` element, but it should be instantiated directly on `jQuery(".home-slide")`